# unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I have been trying to figure out an issue I have been experiencing with Selenium + Chrome driver since mid-November where when it tries to start Chrome it gives the following error:

```
Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)"
```

The issue just started happening and no updates were made to Chrome, the Chrome driver, or even the Selenium web driver.  I have tried to update to the latest versions of Chrome (currently Version 108.0.5359.99 (Official Build) (32-bit)), Chrome Driver (108.0.5359.71), and Selenium Web Driver (C# 4.7.0) but the issue persists.